# Domain joined Windows Server 2019 - not connected to domain network

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, windows-server-2016, local-area-network, wsus

I have two Windows Server 2019 machines in my infrastructure which are connected on 'Guest or Public networks' and I have been unable to switch to domain network.

I have tried many solutions gathered around the Internet but none has been successful so far :

- Restart NLA service
- Replace NIC
- Check DNS (properly registered)

I also notice that Powershell command 'Get-NetConnectionProfile' returns nothing. I guess there is no profile identified.
The problem is that the machines are unable to get Windows Update packages from our WSUS machine.

What else can I do?

Comment: When you say that you checked DNS, what exactly did you check?

Comment: I have three DNS servers which are all registered in these two machines. I can nslookup each of them seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

The NCP (Network Connection Profile) can be set "the hard way" through in registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles
```

When you expand the `Profiles` key, you will see sub-keys with different GUIDs. Those are the networks you have "joined" till date and the key `Description` contains the networks name. Mostly DNS names, if suffixes were distributed through DHCP.

I you found "your" profile, change the DWORD value of `Category` accordingly:

```
0 (for "Public")
1 (for "Private")
2 (for "Domain")
```

Comment: I have just checked but that key is not populated in my case.

Comment: Then your NCP is not populated and the NLA is defunc'd. Check if NLA, Listener and Logon Serives are up and running and that no errors are beeing logged.

Comment: Ok I will check these and let you know. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent all day on this and is a niche answer, so I hope no one else will need it, but it may be useful for someone else.  We had a power user 'fiddler'!

Running

```
Get-NetConnectionProfile
```

produced nothing.  It should produces something, even unconfigured.  My list of keys in reg key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles
```

Was empty.  Turns our our 'power user' revoked permissions for `NT Service\netprofm` at the `NetworkList` Key and below.  Readding permissions for this service account and disabling/reenabling the nic created a key and actually showed on the domain network.

To get the correct permissions, check against another PC on your network as there are a few permissions under Advanced permissions to restore it back to how it was.
[image: image below in case you don't have another machine]